# Why can't I call a method on a variable of a union type?

Tags: typescript, union-types

Unexpectedly, I got a compiler error when I tried to call a method on a variable of a union type. I've isolated the issue, see the code below. I wonder what prevents the compiler from understanding that `baz` should be `string`. Is it some kind of edge case that just isn't implemented (yet?) in the compiler? Or is there some fundamental reason for this code not to be valid?

TypeScript version: 2.0.6

The error is: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

```
declare class A {
    foo(arg: number[] | number): string;
}

declare class B {
    foo(arg: number[]): string;
}

declare let bar: A | B;

let baz = bar.foo([3000]);
```

([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo(arr%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7C%20number)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo(arr%3A%20number%5B%5D)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20bar%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20baz%20%3D%20bar.foo(%5B3000%5D)%3B%0D%0A))

It starts working if I use method overloads in the class `A` instead of a union type. However, my problem is that real `A` and `B` are defined in 3rd party type definitions that are relatively difficult to change.

Answer (score 2):

You'd might expect the type of `bar.foo` to be:

```
(arg: number[] | number) => string;
```

But it is in fact:

```
((arr: number | number[]) => string) | ((arr: number[]) => string)
```

And this type is indeed not callable.

If you change `B` to:

```
declare class B {
    foo(arr: number[] | number): string;
}
```

Then the error goes away (you can obviously change `A.foo` to match `B`).

---

#### Edit

The type:

```
((arr: number | number[]) => string) | ((arr: number[]) => string)
```

Is not callable because the compiler doesn't refer which one of those functions should be called.
If it was able to refer that it would have had it as type `(arg: number[] | number) => string` to begin with.

The reason that it works when you're doing this:

```
declare class A {
    foo(arg: number): string;
    foo(arg: number[]): string;
}
```

Is that now the type `A | B` has a common method: `foo(arg: number[]): string`.
So the type of `bar.foo` is `(arr: number[]) => string` and there's no conflict like before.

Comment: "And this type is indeed not callable." Why isn't it?

Comment: It seems to me the compiler could be smart enough to understand that these two definitions (my initial version and with overloads) are effectively the same thing. But probably I'm missing some important reason for this not to happen. I wonder whether this has been already discussed in the TS project on GitHub.

Comment: I'm not sure why the compiler isn't smart enough in these cases. Try to open an issue and see what they say